# Javascript onclick: how to pass the event variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick

I have an `<asp:Panel>`, and when the user clicks on it, I want to show a `<div>` using Javascript. I do this to prevent the need of a postback to the server (I want a highly interactive client side showing/hiding of subcontent). I use the following code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="FilterButton" OnClick="showFilterPanel(); return false;"/>

function showFilterPanel()
{
    //do some code that shows the div...
}
```

This works because of the `return false;` statement at the end. I would now like to change the function to use `e.stopPropagation()` instead of the `return false;` inside the html. I was told this is the better way of doing this, but I'm not 100% sure what the differences are between "`return false;`" and "`e.stopPropagation()`", and why one is better than the other.

Either way, I don't know the correct syntax of how to pass the event. I tried the following but the parameter e is not correctly passed:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="FilterButton" OnClick="showFilterPanel(sender);"/>

function showFilterPanel(e)
{
    //do some code that shows the div...
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The following don't seem to work either:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="FilterButton" OnClick="showFilterPanel(this);"/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="FilterButton" OnClick="showFilterPanel(event);"/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="FilterButton" OnClick="showFilterPanel(e);"/>
```

I tested the correctness by using an alert message if the function runs, and checking for javascript errors. The errors I get were: "e is undefined" and "stopPropagation is not a method for object".

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the event parameter because you don't have it.

The way to get it is to register events using `addEventListener`.

```
var elm = document.getElementById("FilterButton");
elm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can also do:

```
elm.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

But this notation causes issues if you want to add multiple event listeners.

---

`e.stopPropagation()` is better because:

- `return false` also does `e.preventDefault()`. Most instances I've seen where `return false` is used the intention was actually `preventDefault()`, and not `stopPropagation()`. `stopPropagation()` only very rarely applies. So why not say which one you wanted? (or both!)
- `return false` will not be called if an uncaught error occurs in your function. Imagine an `onclick` on an `a` that performs `some_action()`, then prevents default by `return false`. If `some_action()` throws an error the default action will *not* be cancelled and you might end up somewhere you didn't expect.

---

```
showFilterPanel(this);
```

`this` will point to the HTML element (FilterButton)

---

```
showFilterPanel(event);
```

Will try to reference a global variable `event` (which doesn't exist)

---

```
showFilterPanel(e);
```

Will try to reference a global variable `e` (which doesn't exist)

---

In older browsers (Internet Explorer) there was a global variable `event` (typically `window.event`) that had the *most recent* event. This makes it easier to get the event if you're using your notation. I'm not a big fan of this approach. I don't like the global dependency.